# encode data on client side JavaScript and decode on server side PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, server, decoding

I want to encode my data on client side and send that data to server and let server decode that data which was encoded by client.
Or data can be encoded/decoded client to client or server to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this. Please see below example for client to client encoding and decoding.

```js
let userinfo = {
 id: 10, 
        name: '马克斯',
 username: 'Sanny', 
 company: 'Google'
};
let dataToencode = encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(userinfo))));
let dataTodecode = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(window.atob(decodeURIComponent(dataToencode))));

console.log('After encode: ',dataToencode);
console.log('After decode: ',dataTodecode);
```

In server side (PHP) you can encode/decode data as below.

```
1. Encode data on server side

rawurlencode(base64_encode(rawurlencode(json_encode($userinfo))));

2. Decode data on server side

json_decode(rawurldecode(base64_decode(rawurldecode($userinfo))));
```

You can encode/decode data by client/server side. You can use any combination to encode/decode data. For example encode data from client and decode from server. Or else encode from server and decode on client side.

Comment: Is this solution works for special characters as well ??